# PyTorch element-wise filter layer

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Hi, I want to add element-wise multiplication layer to duplicate the input to multi-channels like this figure. (So, the input size M x N and multiplication filter size M x N is same), as illustrated in this figure

[image]

I want to add custom initialization value to filter, and also want them to get gradient while training. However, I can't find element-wise filter layer in PyTorch. Can I make it? Or is it just impossible in PyTorch?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In pytorch you can always implement your own layers, by making them subclasses of `nn.Module`. You can also have trainable parameters in your layer, by using [`nn.Parameter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#parameters).
Possible implementation of such layer might look like

```
import torch
from torch import nn

class TrainableEltwiseLayer(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n, h, w):
        super(TrainableEltwiseLayer, self).__init__()
        self.weights = nn.Parameter(torch.Tensor(1, n, h, w))  # define the trainable parameter

    def forward(self, x):
        # assuming x is of size b-n-h-w
        return x * self.weights  # element-wise multiplication
```

You still need to worry about initializing the weights. look into [`nn.init`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch-nn-init) on ways to init weights. Usually, one init the weights of all the net prior to training and prior to loading any stored model (so partially trained models can override random init). Something like

```
model = mymodel(*args, **kwargs)  # instantiate a model
for m in model.modules():
    if isinstance(m, nn.Conv2d):
       nn.init.normal_(m.weights.data)  # init for conv layers
    if isinstance(m, TrainableEltwiseLayer):
       nn.init.constant_(m.weights.data, 1)  # init your weights here...
```